# Strictness optimization and memory allocation in Haskell

Tags: optimization, haskell, functional-programming

I've been learning some Haskell by implementing a feature selection algorithm.

I've gotten the performance from 20s on a benchmark dataset down to 5s, where the C program handles the same dataset in 0.5s. The dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/nlhepler/HMrmr/blob/master/test_nci9_s3.csv). To run, call the compiled binary like so: `./Mrmr 10 test_nci9_s3.csv`.

The code is [here](https://github.com/nlhepler/HMrmr/blob/master/Mrmr.hs), and I'm interested in optimizing mutualInfoInnerLoop:

```
mutualInfoInnerLoop :: Double -> Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector (Int, Int) -> Double -> (Int, Int, Double) -> Double
mutualInfoInnerLoop n xys !acc (!i, !j, !px_py)
    | n == 0 || px_py == 0 || pxy == 0 = acc
    | otherwise                        = pxy * logBase 2 ( pxy / px_py ) + acc
    where
        pxy = ( fromIntegral . U.foldl' accumEq2 0 $ xys ) / n
        accumEq2 :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> Int
        accumEq2 !acc (!i', !j')
            | i' == i && j' == j = acc + 1
            | otherwise          = acc
```

The profiler says:

```
COST CENTRE                    MODULE               %time %alloc

mutualInfoInnerLoop            Main                  75.0   47.9
mutualInfo                     Main                  14.7   32.1
parseCsv                       Main                   5.9   13.1
CAF                            GHC.Float              1.5    0.0
readInt                        Main                   1.5    1.2
doMrmr                         Main                   1.5    4.0
```

Which shows mutualInfoInnerLoop as making 50% of the allocations, with 75% of the runtime in the program. The allocations are disconcerting.

Also, the Core for that function has a signature:

```
mutualInfoInnerLoop_rXG
  :: GHC.Types.Double
     -> Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base.Vector (GHC.Types.Int, GHC.Types.Int)
     -> GHC.Types.Double
     -> (GHC.Types.Int, GHC.Types.Int, GHC.Types.Double)
     -> GHC.Types.Double
[GblId,
 Arity=4,
 Caf=NoCafRefs,
 Str=DmdType U(L)LU(L)U(U(L)U(L)U(L))m]
```

Showing most of the parameters as being Lazily evaluated and boxed (as opposed to strict and unboxed).

I've tried BangPatterns, I've tried MagicHash, and I can't seem to make it go faster.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you have tried ghc -O2 already?

Comment: Yes, I have. The source is also annotated with `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` and `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 -fexcess-precision -funbox-strict-fields #-}`

Comment: Can you provide the `Int` and file you use for benchmarking?

Comment: Certainly, the Int is 10 and the dataset can be found at https://github.com/nlhepler/HMrmr/blob/master/test_nci9_s3.csv

Comment: The core is unsurprising.  You've annotated `mutualInfoInnerLoop` as NOINLINE, so GHC won't inline it.  As a consequence, none of the arguments can be unboxed.  What happens if you change that `NOINLINE` to `INLINE`?

Comment: If the idea is to meet or beat the C code then we need that too.

Comment: I've annotated it as `NOINLINE` so that it would show up on the profile. The timing isn't all that different, shaves off a half-second, maybe. All the time and allocation that was previously spent in mutualInfoInnerLoop now shows up in mutualInfo. And from what I've read, inlining and unboxing are unrelated things, see [link](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC)

Comment: @Lance: if you want it to show up in the profile, you should use the `SCC` pragma (sec. 5.1.1, http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/profiling.htm).  Inlining and unboxing are two different concepts, but GHC only unboxes variables in certain cases that most commonly arise from inlining functions.

Comment: What compiler options are you using, and which version of GHC?  The `mutualInfoInnerLoop` seems to be getting entirely unboxed for me.  I did change from using a tuple to a custom strict data type, `data T = T !Int !Int !Double`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Also using strict bytestrings makes a pretty significant difference.

Comment: `-O2 -fexcess-precision -funbox-strict-fields` with GHC 7.0.4. I also tried a datatype conversion at some point, didn't help. And you're right, strict bytestrings saves us another couple fractions of a second. My concern though is still the profile, which shows allocation happening in the inner loop -- I'd like to know what is causing that and how to stop it, if at all possible. I should probably go look at other statistical packages, see how they handle computing joint probabilities quickly.

Comment: The problem is the U.foldl'. I just wonder if it is normal that it allocates that much space.

Comment: @ondra You're RIGHT! In fact, changing it to a foldr' made it another half-second faster (but only in that spot -- changing it elsewhere makes things slower ... very strange).

Comment: -fllvm helps quite a bit too, 25% or so faster with LLVM 2.9 compared to my baseline 64-bit GHC 7.2.1 system.

Comment: @NathanHowell Good to know. I suppose I should set up a more recent environment.

Comment: Okay, looked into Data.Vector implementation -- `foldr'` shouldn't be faster than `foldl'`, as `foldr'` is just `foldl'` with a `flip` of the function passed to it. `foldl'` itself is based on a monadic `foldlM` construct.

Comment: Yes, and the foldlM ultimately calls basicUnsafeIndexM; interestingly enough, when you call the basicUnsafeIndexM yourself, it gets about 0.5s slower... it probably has to do with INLINE_STREAM, which optimizes some things slightly better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm by far no expert at this, but I do see one small improvement. In your source I see this:

```
mutualInfo n ... = foldl' (mutualInfoInnerLoop n $ U.zip xs ys) ...
```

You don't need to check `n == 0` every single time the function is invoked, since you never change the `n` argument when you invoke it. The `xys` argument doesn't change, either, meaning that `pxy` does not change across invocations, since it depends solely on `xys` and `n`. Let's take advantage of these things to make sure a closure is created which evaluates these things only once.

```
mutualInfoInnerLoop n xys
  | n == 0 || pxy == 0 = const
  | otherwise          = go
  where pxy = (fromIntegral . U.foldl' accumEq2 0 $ xys) / n
        accumEq2 :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> Int
        accumEq2 !acc (!i', !j')
              | i' == i && j' == j = acc + 1
              | otherwise          = acc
        go !acc (!i, !j, !px_py)
          | px_py == 0 = acc
          | otherwise  = pxy * logBase 2 ( pxy / px_py ) + acc
```

I'm not sure if GHC is smart enough to perform this optimization on its own, nor am I sure this saves much time/space, but it's the best I've got. With those bang patterns sprinkled all over, I wonder if this is a case of too much strictness.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I actually ended up moving the n == 0 into doMrmr, seemed like a good idea. As for this construction though, without unpacking i or j we can't construct accumEq2 -- which makes me wonder if the dynamically-constructed nature of accumEq2 is the problem.

Comment: Actually, all those bang patterns seem to help, shave off a half-second (we're actually at around 4s).

Comment: Oh I forgot i and j are used in accumEq2. My bad.